# Android Firebase Phone Authentication - Code not sent for the second time on Huawei Phone

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase phone authentication which works perfectly on all android devices. I am experiencing a strange behaviour in new Huawei phones. When I install my app for the first time then that phone receives verification code by SMS but after that, the same phone with the same SIM(phone number) never receives verification code.

In this case the method

```
@Override
 public void onCodeSent(String verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token)
```

is never called and the method

```
@Override
public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential)
```

is called and the SMS code is null in it.

I have tried every possible way but nothing works in this case.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#onverificationcompletedphoneauthcredential says that in some cases there is no need to send code although they didn't mention what can be those cases , may be you having one of them, that should not be a problem though , if that method is not called then don't show them screen to enter code

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan actually I need firebase user token id from firebase user because I have to send it to my server to verify if the user token is valid (checked by firebase admin sdk). In this case when I do not receive the SMS code, I can't get firebase user because it is null so I am unable to extract firebase user token id from null user